# Halal or Haram: Working for a company that develops a dating app

Tags: halal-haram

Assalam-o-Alaikum,

I have been offered a job at a company that develops and operates a dating app. My job would include working directly on the app. The app is a personality-based people matching service, that can connect people based on their personality types for purpose of friendship and dating. As it is personality-based dating, they blur user pictures, so 'Pardah' doesn't look like an issue in the app.

Now, as dating usually leads to Haram, am I allowed to work in this job? Also, as the management is non-muslim, I will have no control making sure if people use the app for only Halal purposes, what to do in this scenario?

This is a really great opportunity for my career, which would give me a great boost financially. However, at the same time, I am afraid to not get into this if this is Haram. Please help me with what should be done according to Islamic rulings.

Thank you, brother.

Comment: There is no need to ask a question. A Mumin (beliver) stays away from Haram actions, nor does he support or contribute Haram actions.

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the situations in life when Allah tests us with choices. If you believe in Allah, ask Him for right path, pray 2 nafl and ask for the right job. Real blessing is not money, real blessing is feel of being obedient when you go to bed. This world is very small, you will surely get good opportunity.